# Vaadin Flow: setting the title

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, html-title

I currently try to set the `title` of the page.

---

### Scenario

```
public class A extends FlexLayout implements RouterLayout {}

@Route(value = "b", layout = A.class)
public class B extends FlexLayout{}
@Route(value = "c", layout = A.class)
public class C extends FlexLayout{}
```

---

### Attempts

1. To do so I tried to  call `UI.getCurrent().getPage().setTitle("demo title")` during `afterNavigation`. Unfortunately this does not work for the initial navigation  (and neither worked adding an `attachListener`).
2. I also tried configuring it using the `PageConfigurator` on the outermost `RouterLayout` like this:

```java
    @Override
    public void configurePage(InitialPageSettings settings) {
        settings.addMetaTag("title", "demo title");
        settings.addMetaTag("og:title", "demo title");

        settings.addFavIcon("icon", "frontend/images/favicon.ico", "48x48");
    }
```

3. `HasDynamicTitle` only seems to work if the implementing class also defines the `@Route` but not the encapsulating `RouterLayout`

---

### Issue

For some reason the `Router` itself sets the title during navigation.

[image: Stacktrace of the setTitleCall]

The `Router` defines the title using JS and redefining `document.title` while `Page.setTitle` seems to only modify the `html.head.title` tag.

---

### Question

How does one set the title in a single spot?
How does one prevent the `Router` form setting the title to the value of the current URL?

---

### Note

Using the `@PageTitle` annotation is not an option as in my case the title is not known at compiletime.

Comment: Could you try to call this `UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJavaScript("document.title = $0",your_title);` in your `attachListener`? And if this doesn't work then implement the `BeforeEnterObserver` and call it inside `beforeEnter`.
But a `HasDynamicTitle ` should work based on the documentation. So might be a bug :/

Comment: Thank you for replying. I guess Ill try to add a JS changelistener during UI init. But thats a dirty hack imo.

Comment: I ended up setting the title by creating an interface that implements `HasDynamicTitle` and adding that interface to each and every `Route` endpoint.

Comment: I dont consider this workaround a solution as it creates the possibilty for inconsistant title because someone who adds a new `Route` has to know / remember that setting the interface is required.

Answer (score 3):

## Fixed title

If you have an unchanging page title you can just set it with an annotation [`@PageTitle`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/router/PageTitle.html).

```java
@PageTitle("home")
class HomeView extends Div {

  HomeView(){
    setText("This is the home view");
  }
}
```

## Dynamic  title

The official Vaadin Flow documentation suggests to use the [`HasDynamicTitle`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.16/com/vaadin/flow/router/HasDynamicTitle.html).

Example:

```java
@Route(value = "blog")
class BlogPost extends implements HasDynamicTitle, HasUrlParameter<Long> {
  private String title = "";

  @Override
  public String getPageTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  @Override
  public void setParameter(BeforeEvent event,
        @OptionalParameter Long parameter) {
    if (parameter != null) {
      title = "Blog Post #" + parameter;
    } else {
      title = "Blog Home";
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-page-titles.html)

Comment: As I pointed out in Attempt#3 using the `HasDynamicTitle`works fine but is redundant.
My scenario involves a single parent that has a lot of children with different routes. 
I would like to define the `title` once in that parent layout (a `RouterLayout`) like `PageTitle` would allow you to.

Comment: By childen do you mean they are programmatically extending the mother component? So you want to avoid that every child has to implement the interface but setting each route for each child dynamically?

Comment: No unfortunately not. In that case `HasDynamicTitle` would work.
I my case I have a lot of classes with `Route`annotations. These annotations reference a common `RouterLayout` by using the `layout` property.

Comment: I added a scenario section for clarification.

Comment: I think there is no other way except you did. If I understood you right this was once considered a possible solution for your problem but got scrapped: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4802